# I can see port 21 is open in windows server 2016 using cmd prompt but is says closed when checked online

Tags: tcp, ftp, windows-server-2016

I can see the port 21 is open in my windows server 2016 using netstat -a in command prompt but when i checked in online tool https://networkappers.com/tools/open-port-checker#.Wnm8vKiWZPY it says closed. Can some one help me please.

I am using this port for ftp via TCP.

Thanks,
Kshan

Answer (score 0):

netstat only shows if a process is listening on the port. But this does not mean that the port is accessible from outside.

First, it might be that the process is only listing on a local IP address. Then a firewall might block access to the port from outside - this can be firewall settings on the server machine and/or firewalls somewhere in the network.

Comment: thanks for the reply.

I added the inbound rule in server firewall for port 21. Can you please let me know how to open this port so that i can access from internet.

Thanks,
Kshan

Comment: @kshan2k18:  I've mentioned several points where a problem might be. You've tuned only one. Your question provides no information where firewalls might be in your network and if your application is even listening to an external IP (instead of only local IP) in the first place. Since I don't know how things are configured I cannot say what you specifically need to change - but an unspecific question results in an unspecific answer only.

Comment: I am sorry i am new to windows server. I dint understood what "First, it might be that the process is only listing on a local IP address." this mean.

How to check the firewalls in network. Can you please help me.

Comment: @kshan2k18: since I have no idea of your network I cannot tell you where the firewalls are in the network and how to configure these - ask your network administrators instead. As for netstat: it might help if you would provide the relevant part of the netstat output. Then one can see if the process is listening only on a local IP or not.

Comment: I use dlink router. Anyway below is the output of netstat
C:\Windows\system32>netstat -a
Active Connections

Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
  TCP    0.0.0.0:21             qsurveydemo1windows:0  LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:80             qsurveydemo1windows:0  LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:135            qsurveydemo1windows:0  LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:445            qsurveydemo1windows:0  LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:3306           qsurveydemo1windows:0  LISTENING
Also i can connect to port 80 from outside but not for port 21.

Comment: @kshan2k18: *0.0.0.0:21* - ok, it is listening on a public IP. *"I use dlink router"* - There are many many different dlink routers. Please study the manual how to configure this device. Apart from that: if you are behind a simple NAT router and trying to make FTP available from outside it will likely not work. Port 21 is not enough because FTP uses dynamic ports  for the data transfer. Unless your router specifically supports this it is kind of impossible to get it working.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Much appreciated. :) I will check all the mentioned possibilities and get back to you.

Comment: Figured it out. In google cloud console there is a firewall blocking our connection. When i enabled the port i can connect through ftp. Thanks for your help.